# When using CloudFlare 301 redirect, why does a script not render?

Tags: javascript, http-status-code-301, cloudflare

I run CodeFund.io (ethical ad platform) and we are trying to consolidate our domains. One of the issues we have is that some of our publishers use codefund.io and others use codefund.app domains.

I set up a 301 redirect on CloudFlare (with codefund.dev as a test domain) to see if we can make this switch.

Here's a website I launched that tests it out:

https://csb-6ywv1ynjmn.netlify.com/

In the browser console (network tab), I see two reqeusts. The first is made to codefund.dev which returns a 301. The 2nd is made to codefund.app and does not return anything.

Does anyone know why the request in the network console does not return anything from the 2nd request?

Thanks!

Eric

Comment: I don't see any redirect in the browser. Just 200 codes and then 304 or reloads. I don't think your 301 is happening at all.

Answer (score 0):

I actually found out it's because I had an ad blocker installed. It looks like the ad blocker will use the original request domain and not the redirect domain in the whitelisting check.

This is good news